# Case-insensitive index for a case-sensitive property

Tags: ruby, datamapper

I have something like:

```
class User
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :username, Text
end
```

I want usernames to be case-sensitive, so users can make usernames as they choose. What's the best way to then search for usernames in a case-insensitive way?

if I make a user named 'TestUser', I want to be able to access it with something like

```
User.first(:username => 'testuser')
```

I thought about making a username_downcased property that uses a validates_with_method to make a downcased version of the username property for indexing, but I had problems getting that to work.

Comment: Are you sure you really want username uniqueness to be case sensitive? That would mean 'Apple' and 'apple' would be two different users.

Comment: Don't you mean "I want usernames to preserve case for display purposes but be case insensitive for all other purposes"?

Comment: You're right, though if I have a property that is case-insensitive on lookup, I can use that to validate uniqueness with a validation method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of finagling I found a solution, but I would be very surprised if it is the best one.

```
class User
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :username, Text
  property :username_lower, Text

  validates_with_method :lower_username
  validates_uniqueness_of :username_lower, :message => 'Username is already taken'

  def lower_username
    self.username_lower = self.username.downcase
    true
  end

end
```

Case-sensitive name stored in username, but case-insensitive indexing can be done on username_lower.